# Elasticsearch truncating _version field using external versioning system

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use dynamic mapping in Elasticsearch (version 1.1) to persist an object. I have pre-created the Index, and I am using the Post api to index the object as follows

```
PUT /testprecreatedindex/NotCreatedMapping/Id1?version=3155378975111111119&version_type=external
{
   "title": "Test Blog",
   "Id": "Id1"
}
```

Response from elasticsearch in Sense (0.8.10)

```
{
   "_index": "testprecreatedindex",
   "_type": "NotCreatedMapping",
   "_id": "Id1",
   "_version": 3155378975111111000,
   "created": true
}
```

I am intentionally giving version as DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks as it is less than [(2^63)-1](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support/) limit of elasticsearch.
Still the result indicate that the version got truncated or round off.

Any clues to what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rounding off is an artifact related to SENSE  implementation more precisely way numbers are represented by [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) which has a precision of 53 bits

The version data should have been stored properly in elasticsearch .

You can verify via a command line curl query.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/testprecreatedindex/NotCreatedMapping/Id1'
```